# Regex 'OR' seems to not behave as expected

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to build a regex for a string with the followings constraints :

```
 should only contain 'X', 'O', 'T', '_', ';' 
 'T' and 'O' should occur only once and can be anywhere in the string
  'X', '_', ';'  may occur zero to n times
```

Here are few valid examples :

```
"X__;O_T;___"
"T__;_XX_;_XO"
"T__;OX_;_X_"
"OT"
```

This is the regex I have right now :

```
/^([X;_]*T[X;_]*O)|([X;_]*O[X;_]*T);$ */i
```

The  above seems to pass  the below input as valid:

```
T__;_X__OO; //which is not valid
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `^[X;_]*(?:T[X;_]*(?:O[X;_]*)?|O[X;_]*(?:T[X;_]*)?)?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mVnRz7/1).

Comment: Why is `"OX"` valid? there's no `"T"` in it...

Comment: Can you use lookaheads? `^(?![^O]*O[^O]*O)(?![^T]*T[^T]*T)[TOX;_]*$` should work. See https://regex101.com/r/mVnRz7/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a lookahead you may use

```
^(?=[^O]*O[^O]*$)(?=[^T]*T[^T]*$)[TOX;_]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1EPcHp/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^O]*O[^O]*$)` - there must be any 0+ chars other than `O`, then `O`, and then any 0+ chars other than `O` up to the end of the string
- `(?=[^T]*T[^T]*$)` - there must be any 0+ chars other than `T`, then `T`, and then any 0+ chars other than `T` up to the end of the string
- `[TOX;_]*` - 0+ `T`, `O`, `X`, `;`, `_` chars
- `$` - end of string.

A non-lookaround approach based on alternation is also possible:

```
^[X;_]*(?:T[X;_]*O|O[X;_]*T)[X;_]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1EPcHp/2).

**Details**

- `^` - string start
- `[X;_]*` - 0+ `T`, `O`, `X`, `;`, `_` chars
- `(?:T[X;_]*O|O[X;_]*T)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `T[X;_]*O` - `T`, any 0+ `T`, `O`, `X`, `;`, `_` chars, `O`
  - `|` - or
  - `O[X;_]*T`  - `O`, any 0+ `T`, `O`, `X`, `;`, `_` chars, `T`
- `[X;_]*` - 0+ `T`, `O`, `X`, `;`, `_` chars
- `$` - string end.

Comment: My Bad typo in the valid examples, it is 'should occur ONLY once' as oppose to  'could occur once'

Comment: @Snedden27 Updated the solution.